# RNN Model does not seem to predict an array but elements in an array (Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have data consisting of coordinates which are lists like this

```
coordinate = [x,y,z,t,dx,dy,dz,dt]
```

I have paths, each of which is a list of coordinates 
`path = [coordinate1,coordinate2,...]`

I am currently a numpy array of paths `paths = [path1,path2,path3,...]` into the following neural network:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(None,8),activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=(None,8),return_sequences=False,activation='relu'))                                                                                                                                         
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(8,activation='softmax'))
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3,decay=1e-5)
model.compile(optimizer=opt,loss='mean_squared_logarithmic_error',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

I would like my network to be able to look at two coordinates on a path and then predict the third coordinate. The shape of the training data X_data is (number of paths,number of coordinates of a path,number of coordinate features=8) and the shape of my `y_data` is (number of paths, number of coordinate_features=8).

I can feed this data in fine but the prediction which comes out is clearly wrong.

Predicted value: `[[1.9864183e-07 8.3630894e-08 2.6606214e-01 4.4643345e-01 1.8504219e-08 6.8312538e-09 2.4231732e-09 2.8750402e-01]]`

True Value: `[[ 5.24782e+00 -1.82606e+01  1.13000e+02  2.75222e+02  7.93857e-03 7.93857e-03  1.00000e-01  2.00000e+02]]`

They are not even at the same order of magnitude. What is it predicting?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO; kindly spend some time to see how you should properly format *code blocks* (done it for you this time)...

Comment: Thanks, Apologies for that. I completely missed the code blocks formatting.

Comment: This seems to be a regression task (output is continuous), while your network is doing clasification, that's why the results don't make any sense.

Comment: Are you suggesting that an LSTM would not be the best way or is it possible to change my network for regression? I've changed the activation functions to be linear rather relu or softmax and this gives me more reasonable values but there are still too high.